# error: window.parent.sayhello is not a function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got a js function that is defined in a JScript.js file. This file is defined on the masterpage. I am trying to call the sayhello function in this file from the inIframe.aspx page. This inIframe.aspx 'runs' inside the webform1.aspx page and the webform1.aspx page has a masterpage called masterWithJs.master.

when I hit :

```
http://localhost:8022/inIframe.aspx
```

I get an script error in firebug:

```
window.parent.sayhello is not a function
```

masterpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="masterWithJs.master.cs"
    Inherits="IFrameJS.masterWithJs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        <script src="Scripts/JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

webform1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterWithJs.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="IFrameJS.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <iframe id="myIframe" runat="server"></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

inIframe.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="inIframe.aspx.cs" Inherits="IFrameJS.inIframe" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        this is the iframe page
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.parent.sayhello();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JScript1.js

```
function sayhello() {
    alert( 'hello');
}
```

webform1.aspx behindcode:

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myIframe.Attributes.Add("src","inIframe.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Then i think i know the solution

Try to create a utility function for the path of the script holding the function you call 
like this one

```
   public static string ReferenceScript(string scriptFile)
    {
        //this line is just an example "~/include/js/" of the path of the js file
        var filePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/include/js/" + scriptFile);
        return "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + filePath + "\"></script>";
    }
```

and then call it in the master page HTML
in the beginning of the body

```
//EtPortalEntities.um_utility is an instanse of my name space you should put yours
<%= EtPortalEntities.um_utility.ReferenceScript("jquery.js")%>
```

and then try i think it should work if its all about paths as i think

Regards

Comment: thanks everyone!! the script file did not get loaded according to firebug , now it does!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the empty `Content` control with `ContentPlaceHolderID="head"` from the `webform1.aspx` page.

When you have the `Content` control in the page, it will replace what you have in the `ContentPlaceHolder` in the master page, so the Javascript file will not be included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove Content tag for the "head" ContentPlaceholderID from the webform1.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for

```
window.opener.sayhello();
```

Comment: `window.opener` is for opened windows. `window.parent` is correct for inline frames.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the window.parent bit at all:

In your inIframe.aspx file, just call the function with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    sayhello();
</script>
```

The javascript engine will find the 'sayHello' function from all the script files/sections it has loaded.